# How to modify nature style?

Tags: biblatex

I am using the Nature citation style. I would like to change the position of the article year and change a little format.

This is my sample code.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,refsegment=chapter,style=nature,firstinits=true,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,sorting=none,clearlang=true,natbib=true,intitle=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{date}{#1;}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{
        \clearfield{url}%
        \clearfield{urldate}%
        \clearfield{review}%
        \clearfield{series}%
        \clearfield{eprint}%
        \clearfield{eprinttype}%
    }{}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\textbf{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textbf{#1}\isdot}
```

This is a result
[image]

I would like to move the article year and put it after the journal name without round brackets.

This is my expected result.
[image]

Please suggest to me.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the following redefinitions.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=nature,
  intitle=true,
  isbn=false, doi=false, url=false, eprint=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\textbf{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textbf{#1}\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {%
      \newunit
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
    }%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit
}
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry 1998; 19, 377–395.]

---

If you want to know which bibmacros or field definitions you need to change, you usually have to have a look at the source of the bibliography style you are using. For `@article`, the type discussed in the question, [`nature.bbx` has](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/blob/0dffc9c40ecc37655f6501f69076f23f65f4c245/nature.bbx#L290-L334)

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articletitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newblock
    }
    {}%
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

Some guessing and a bit of trial and error shows that the bibmacro `journal+issuetitle` prints the journal title and volume, number information. `note+pages` prints the pages and `issue+date` the date.

So step one is to redefine `issue+date` to do nothing. The second step is to insert code to print the date after the journal title. To do that we redefine  `journal+issuetitle`, [which is originally defined in `nature.bbx` as](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/blob/0dffc9c40ecc37655f6501f69076f23f65f4c245/nature.bbx#L200-L214)

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {%
      \newunit
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
    }%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit
}
```

You'll notice that the code we added to `journal+issuetitle` is a simplified [version of `nature.bbx`'s `issue+date`](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/blob/0dffc9c40ecc37655f6501f69076f23f65f4c245/nature.bbx#L183-L198)

```
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {%
      \iffieldundef{issue}
        {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
        {%
          \printtext[parens]{%
            \printfield{issue}%
            \setunit*{\addspace}%
            \usebibmacro{date}%
          }%
        }%
    }%
  \newunit  
}
```

The bottom line is: If you want to know which macros you need to redefine, check the implementation in the `.bbx` and `.cbx` files and chase down the bibmacro definitions.